# Reversing a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I don't really have a good way to explain in words what i wont to do.So im just going to have an example.

this is what the variable would be before.

```
var foo ="foo";
```

this is what i wont it be after.

```
var foo ="oof";
```

I hope that you under stand what i'm asking!

Thinks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var foo="start".split("").reverse().join("");
```